# How to get a row count of another table, using SELECT column as a WHERE clause using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting posts from a 'posts' table in a MySQL database, but I want one of the columns returned to be a comment count from a comments table using the rows selected post id. My DB is relational so the comment table has a post id field (comment_post_id). Here's what I have, but this query is creating a syntax error in PHPMYAdmin:

```
SELECT post_id, post_title, post_status, post_image, post_tags, post_views, post_date, user_name, cat_title, 
COUNT(SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = post_id) AS comment_count
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON post_author = user_id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON post_category_id = cat_id
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Post and Comments table columns are laid out as follows:

Post:
post_id, post_title, post_status, post_image, post_tags, post_views, post_date, post_author, post_category_id

Comments:
comment_id, comment_post_id, comment_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to get the count here. Try this way

```
SELECT post_id, post_title, post_status, post_image, post_tags, post_views, post_date, user_name, cat_title, 
(SELECT COUNT(comment_id) FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = post_id) AS comment_count
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON post_author = user_id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON post_category_id = cat_id
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join `comments` with `post` then use `count(comment_id)`. Instead of redundant sub query.

```
SELECT 
    post_id,
    post_title,
    post_status,
    post_image,
    post_tags,
    post_views,
    post_date,
    user_name,
    cat_title,
    COUNT(comment_id) AS comment_count
FROM
    posts
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON post_author = user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    categories ON post_category_id = cat_id
        JOIN
    comments ON post_id = comment_post_id
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```